# проблема с слайдом jssor

Tags: javascript, width

У меня jssor слайдер.Во время загрузки слайдера он расширяется и появляется скролл,но после загрузки сайта все приходит в норму.Что мне делать,можете помочь.Спасибо заранее.
Это мой сайт [webhouse](http://webhouse.am)

Comment: скролл горизонтальный? если да, то это скорее всего из-за трансформации элементов внутри слайдера, например эффект вращения изображения. Думаю, есть смысл просто добавить оверфлой с параметром hidden.

Comment: Да горизонтальныйс,пасибо но не помогла этот вариант

Comment: ок, тогда добавляем супер горячий фикс для любой ситуации: body {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto}. уж это то точно поможет

Comment: спасибо очень,помогла

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше всего `lightSlider` он содержит весь функционал, который только может потребоваться, плюс ко всему он `responsive` и требует меньше производительности.

lightSlider: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/